# Efficiently Assigning Keycloak ID to Entity in Microservices App Secured with Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, security, microservices, keycloak

I'm seeking a solution for assigning a Keycloak Id field in entity within my application, which is secured using Keycloak and follows a microservices architecture. The core concept of the application involves allowing users to create products that can be purchased by other users. I intend to assign the owner's user ID to the newly created Product entity. I've considered a few potential solutions:

1. Retrieving the Keycloak ID using Keycloak Admin.
2. Retrieving the Keycloak ID using Keycloak Events.
3. Retrieving the Keycloak ID by obtaining the principal name and then calling the UserService to locate the user and retrieve their Keycloak ID.

Currently, I can implement the third solution, but it seems somewhat inefficient to obtain the principal name and make an additional call to another service solely to retrieve the object representing the current user.